# ECS CLI key pair error when calling up

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am trying to use Amazon's ECS cli to create a cluster. I keep getting the error:

```
 reason="The key pair 'my-key-pair' does not exist" resourceType="AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
```

I have also run:

```
ecs-cli configure profile --profile-name grantspilsbury --access-key foo --secret-key bar
ecs-cli configure --cluster cluster_test --region us-east-1 --config-name myclusterconfig
```

I have added my-key-pair to ECS and to EC2.

The full log is:

```
~ $ ecs-cli up --keypair my-key-pair --capability-iam --size 2 --instance-type t2.small --force
INFO[0002] Created cluster                               cluster=default region=us-east-1
INFO[0003] Waiting for your CloudFormation stack resources to be deleted...
INFO[0003] Cloudformation stack status                   stackStatus="DELETE_IN_PROGRESS"
INFO[0038] Waiting for your cluster resources to be created...
INFO[0038] Cloudformation stack status                   stackStatus="CREATE_IN_PROGRESS"
INFO[0101] Cloudformation stack status                   stackStatus="CREATE_IN_PROGRESS"
INFO[0164] Cloudformation stack status                   stackStatus="CREATE_IN_PROGRESS"
ERRO[0197] Failure event                                 reason="The key pair 'my-key-pair' does not exist" resourceType="AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
FATA[0197] Error executing 'up': Cloudformation failure waiting for 'CREATE_COMPLETE'. State is 'ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. My issue was I was giving it the full path to the `pem` file rather than the name of the [key on EC2 (link to Ohio region)](https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-2#KeyPairs:sort=keyName). Turning

`ecs-cli up --keypair /home/me/keyPair.pem --capability-iam --size 2 --instance-type t2.medium --cluster-config ec2-tutorial --force`

into

`ecs-cli up --keypair keyPair --capability-iam --size 2 --instance-type t2.medium --cluster-config ec2-tutorial --force`

works as long as there is a key pair on EC2 named `keyPair`

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was passing the filename (keypair.pem) instead of the name of the keypair on AWS. Make sure you pass the **keypair name** as you see on AWS and not the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your key is in a different region from the one where you're attempting to create the image.  Jeff's answer gave me the clue that my keypair was in the default instance (Ohio), but I was creating my instance in my local region.

Answer (score 0):

I was following this tutorial until I found the same issue:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-ec2.html

It had nothing to do with the region, the problem was my Key-Pair wasn't uploaded to the ECS. Maybe it is obvious, but if you are AWS beginner like me, the tutorial instructions are not clear about this.

**Previous step: Create Key-Pair**

If you haven't already done it, first you have to create the Key-Pair that is stored on a **".pem"** file. Following this instructions with the AWS Console, was quite easy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

**Solution:**

The **".pem"** file has to be uploaded. Can be done using the AWS console, following the menu:
EC2 > Network & Security > Key Pairs > "Create Key Pair"

Menu URL: https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=eu-central-1#CreateKeyPair:
(Be careful about the 2 regions defined on this URL)

As it is described on:
https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-add-new-user-with-key-pair-in-aws-ec2/

Answer (score -1):

That means that keypair name does not exist in your EC2 account.

[Simply create it with s per the aws guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#having-ec2-create-your-key-pair)